# Python does not automatically reconnect to db using try / except statement like I intended it to

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, postgresql, try-except

I have a python script below that attempts to make a connection to a sql db. The database was having some connection issues and I want the script to try to reconnect to the db so I added try / except. However the script still does not automatically reconnect with the try / except statement. If anyone can help me with getting my script to reconnect to the db automatically I would greatly appreciate it!

**Code**

```
from __future__ import print_function

try:
    import psycopg2
except ImportError:
    raise ImportError('\n\033[33mpsycopg2 library missing. pip install psycopg2\033[1;m\n')
    sys.exit(1)

import re
import sys
import json
import pprint
import time

outfilepath = "crtsh_output/crtsh_flat_file"

DB_HOST = 'crt.sh'
DB_NAME = 'certwatch'
DB_USER = 'guest'

DELAY = 8

#conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname={0} user={1} host={2}".format(DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_HOST))
#cursor = conn.cursor()

def connect_to_db():
    filepath = 'forager.txt'
#    conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname={0} user={1} host={2}".format(DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_HOST))
#    cursor = conn.cursor()
    with open(filepath) as fp:
        unique_domains = ''
        try:
            conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname={0} user={1} host={2}".format(DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_HOST))
            cursor = conn.cursor()
            for cnt, domain_name in enumerate(fp):
                print("Line {}: {}".format(cnt, domain_name))
                print(domain_name)
                domain_name = domain_name.rstrip()

                cursor.execute('''SELECT c.id, x509_commonName(c.certificate), x509_issuerName(c.certificate), x509_notBefore(c.certificate), x509_notAfter(c.certificate), x509_issuerName(c.certificate), x5$
                FROM certificate c, certificate_identity ci WHERE
                c.id= ci.certificate_id AND ci.name_type = 'dNSName' AND lower(ci.name_value) =
                lower(%s) AND x509_notAfter(c.certificate) > statement_timestamp()''', (domain_name,))


                unique_domains = cursor.fetchall()

                pprint.pprint(unique_domains)

                outfilepath = "crtsh1" + ".json"
                with open(outfilepath, 'a') as outfile:
                        outfile.write(json.dumps(unique_domains, sort_keys=True, indent=4, default=str, ensure_ascii = False))
                time.sleep(DELAY)

        except Exception as error:
        #    print("\n\033[1;31m[!] Unable to connect to the database\n\033[1;m")
            print(str(error))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    connect_to_db()
```

Comment: what's the error you get when connection breaks?

Comment: It just says Killed

Comment: ok there's not much information to magically "fix" your issue. I'm posting how usually it's been done below.

Comment: @AsavPatel I know. Sure, any information you can post is extremely helpful

Comment: You'll likely want to not use "except Exception". That's very rarely the Right Thing. Use the most specific exception you can: at the very least this should be `psycopg2.Error`. As written your "except" will be triggered if, say, outfilepath is not writable.

Answer (score 0):

try/except does not, by itself, re-try anything after an exception.

You could try something like the following (with an optional parameter "tries" to ensure it doesn't keep trying forever).

```
def connect_to_db(tries=0):
    filepath = 'forager.txt'
#    conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname={0} user={1} host={2}".format(DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_HOST))
#    cursor = conn.cursor()
    with open(filepath) as fp:
        unique_domains = ''
        try:
            conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname={0} user={1} host={2}".format(DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_HOST))
            cursor = conn.cursor()
            for cnt, domain_name in enumerate(fp):
                print("Line {}: {}".format(cnt, domain_name))
                print(domain_name)
                domain_name = domain_name.rstrip()

                cursor.execute('''SELECT c.id, x509_commonName(c.certificate), x509_issuerName(c.certificate), x509_notBefore(c.certificate), x509_notAfter(c.certificate), x509_issuerName(c.certificate), x5$
                FROM certificate c, certificate_identity ci WHERE
                c.id= ci.certificate_id AND ci.name_type = 'dNSName' AND lower(ci.name_value) =
                lower(%s) AND x509_notAfter(c.certificate) > statement_timestamp()''', (domain_name,))


                unique_domains = cursor.fetchall()

                pprint.pprint(unique_domains)

                outfilepath = "crtsh1" + ".json"
                with open(outfilepath, 'a') as outfile:
                        outfile.write(json.dumps(unique_domains, sort_keys=True, indent=4, default=str, ensure_ascii = False))
                time.sleep(DELAY)

        except Exception as error:
        #    print("\n\033[1;31m[!] Unable to connect to the database\n\033[1;m")
            if tries < 3:
                time.sleep(1) # give the DB a bit to recover if you want
                connect_to_db(tries+1)
            else:
                raise error
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Unfortunately the process still gets killed even with the updated code you posted. Do you have any other ideas of how to fix this problem?